# Does remembering meanings in two languages help

Tags: meaning

Let me explain, I know 2 languages, portuguese and english. When I learn the meaning of a new word in Japanese, I take note of and try to remember the meaning in english as well as in portuguese. For example, I write "今日 = today / hoje". I do this thinking that this would help because it feels more toward remembering a meaning and not word equivalence.

Does that really help? Or is it a waste of time? Or it actually confuses me?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange! Technically, this question is off-topic, since we're more about how Japanese works than how to learn it. Still, as advice, you might actually be better off trying to remember meanings in -neither- language, and instead connecting the Japanese word directly with whatever it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it can work or not for you, no one can say except you.  Different learning methods work (or not) for different people. For example, some people use special mnemonic methods to memorize Kanji using various imagery or presumed similarities between a particular kanji and objects such as trees, animals, etc.  For me, this method does not work -- I just learn by breaking down a kanji into radicals.   Conclusion:  if you find that noting down the meaning in two languages is helpful to YOU, then it's not a waste of time.